# Problem with "write" function in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, concurrency

I am trying to write 2 server/client programs under Linux, in which they communicate through named pipes. The problem is that sometimes when I try to write from the server into a pipe that doesn't exist anymore (the client has stopped), I get a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error and the server stops completely.

I understand that this is caused by using a O_NONBLOCK parameter when opening the fifo chanel, indicating the point where the program would usually wait until it could write again in the file, but is there a way to stop this behavior, and not halt the entire program if a problem occurs (shouldn't the write command return -1 ad the program continue normally)?

And another strange thing is that this error only occurs when running the programs outside the ide (eclipse). If I run both programs inside eclipse, on error the write function just returns -1 and the programs continues normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish that `write()` to returns -1 on error (and set `errno` to `EPIPE`) instead of *stopping your server completly* when the write end of your pipe is unconnected, you must ignore the [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE) signal with `signal( SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN )`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem  with this undefined behaviour is strange, you could have a memory problem somewhere or you missed a test. ( or Eclipse does something special to handle signals? )

Comment: The problem is definitely with the write function. I've put 2 "perror"'s before and after the write call... and only the first is showing, thus the program exists on the "write" function call. I forgot to mention that when the client closes, it also deletes the file from disk, so the remaining file descriptors from the server points towards... nothing.

Comment: @Dumitru: Without any code to prove what you're saying, this answer seems like the best bet, especially considering all the behaviour you've described in the question.

Comment: You should test with Platypus solution, but the behaviour is strange

Answer (score 0):

To quote the section 2 man page for write:
"[errno=]EPIPE     An attempt is made to write to a pipe or a FIFO that is not open for reading by any process, or that has only one end open (or to a file descriptor created by socket(3SOCKET), using type SOCK_STREAM that is no longer connected to a peer endpoint).  **A SIGPIPE signal will also be sent to the thread. The process dies unless special provisions were taken to catch or ignore the signal.**" [Emphasis mine].

As Platypus said you'll need to ignore the SIGPIPE signal:
`signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`. You could also catch the signal and handle the pipe disconnection in a different way in your server.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can just wrap it into a "try..catch" statement?